# converting string to datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

hey guys,
i want to convert datetime from string, i have string which contains 'GETDATE' now i want to convert the same in datetime, the string in sql server is been defined as varchar(max)

Please reply how can i type cast the GETDATE() function from string to datetieme.

Regards
Abbas Electricwala

Comment: Can you be more exact please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you mean that you have a string that contains the text `GetDate()` like this.

```
declare @S varchar(50)
set @S = 'getdate()'
```

And you want to turn that into a date variable executing `getdate()`.

You could do this since you know what what `getdate()` means.

```
declare @S varchar(50)
set @S = 'getdate()'

declare @D datetime

set @D = (select
            case @S when 'getdate()'
              then getdate()
              else null
            end)
```

Does not really make sense, there probably is more to this than you are telling.

Comment: thanks for that, but is there any way i could do it without such select statement, i mean one line type casting.

Comment: No, not with casting but this is only one line. You can use the code between the parenthesis as a column in a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just date string you can do it like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2009-02-25 15:31:17.888')
```

Answer (score 0):

But... GETDATE() returns a datetime value, not a string value. Just assign the GETDATE() result to your variable.

Sample (may be inacurate):

```
declare @mydate as datetime
set @mydate = GETDATE()
```

Comment: actually i am calling it from stored procedure and stored procedure accepts only string value